# Not able to find the location of gcc package

Tags: gcc

The error says that it cannot find the location of gcc package nor it is installing gcc.

Comment: Please edit your question to accurately show the exact wording.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install build-essential`, a mteta-package that will install the compiler, assembler, linker, and necessary libraries and include files.